# Send form data to php from ajax loaded records

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to send form data using ajax. My index page the records are showing after having been fetched using ajax from remote page.

Below is my page image.

[image: indexpage image]

Each record has comment box I want to store these comments in a data base using ajax.

Below is my jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('body').on('submit','.comment_p',function(){
  var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
  var com_dis= $("#comment_disc").val();
  var cominfo = 'id=' + post_id + '&disc=' + com_dis;
  if(com_dis=='')
     {
    alert('Please add your comment');
  } else{
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"/comment_update.php",
      data:$(".comment_p").serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
           }
     });
  }
  return false;
  });   
});
```

i used `body` on click because these records are loaded from remote page.
and my form is below

```
<div class="panel-zesteve-textarea">
   <form method="post" id="'.$row['id'].'" class="comment_p">
     <input id="post_id" type="hidden" name="post_id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
     <textarea id="comment_disc" name="comment_disc" rows="2" cols="48"></textarea>
     <button id="com_submit" type="submit" class="btn btnbg">Post comment</button>
     <button type="reset" class="[ btn btn-default ]">Cancel</button>
   </form>
```

nowWhen I click on post, comment is working for one record that is the last record. I need to send id no. and textarea value to php page to update in mysql, but both comments are showing same record id and comment. It's not working for sencond one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reference the form with `$(this)`

```
data: $(this).serialize(), instead of `data:$(".comment_p").serialize(),`
```

Comment: hi i got a strange problem, its working only when i comment on last record and then same thing working on other records. on page lode if i directly comment on 2 nd or 3 rd post its not working, i dont understand why.